# Erroneous entity stuck in context

Tags: entity-framework

Can a database context be configured to remove entities that won't save because of, for example, a unique constraint violation?

I want to retry a save with a new entity, but the context is stuck trying to save the original entity. Should I create a new, fresh context?

Comment: Have you tried using `AsNoTracking()`. I've had an issue with this before and that helped.

Comment: Isn't that only for fetches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my dependency injector supply my re-try code with a context factory. So the code can use a new context with every save attempt.